# The file system mount target ip address cannot be found, please pass mount target ip address via mount options

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks, amazon-efs

I'm trying to deploy Open Metadata on EKS according to the [docs](https://docs.open-metadata.org/deployment/kubernetes/eks), but I'm failing to attach the EFS to the cluster.

I've setup the efs driver as described [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/efs-csi.html) and it fails with the message below when I try to run any pod that actually consumes the PV.

```
Failed to resolve "fs-***.efs.my-region-code.amazonaws.com". 
The file system mount target ip address cannot be found, 
please pass mount target ip address via mount options
```

I tried running a minimal example found [here](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-efs-csi-driver/tree/master/examples/kubernetes/static_provisioning), but it fails with the same error.

The efs driver documentation mentions getting the node ip and getting the associated subnet in the cluster VPC, but our deployment has more than one node, which got me thinking the problem could be intermitent, maybe ? I've seen different errors messages, but now I'm stuck in the mentioned one.

Also, I thought I had the wrong subnet, but getting a pod in the cluster and telnet the efs IP works, but not telnet the address, maybe something related with the DNS ?

Thanks in advane

Comment: It's always DNS. But seriously, you should check whether you created an EFS endpoint in the same AZ as the pod that is mounting the file system, that the security group for the EFS endpoint accepts traffic from the pod, and that you can resolve the name of the file system endpoint from the pod.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error likes yours, but I m not sure if we have the same setting, so I will providing the troubleshooting step for you to review if it can helps.

1. if your are using AWS defult DNS server, make sure your VPC has enable `DNS hostnames` and `DNS resolution`, so that your worker node able to resolve the EFS DNS.
2. If you are using your own DNS server, you can force the `efs-csi-node` daemonset in `kube-system` namespace to use the default resolver by adding the following configuration. `169.254.169.253` is the AWS VPC's default resolver. [DNS attributes for your VPC](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-dns.html)
   and [Customer DNS for access EFS](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-efs-csi-driver/issues/285#issuecomment-855633486)

```
hostNetwork: true
dnsPolicy: "None"
dnsConfig:
  nameservers:
    - 169.254.169.253
```

My case was using my own DNS servers, which step 2 solve my issues.

3. you need to make sure the mount target you creaed from EFS is in the same subnet as worker node and then the nodes were able to resolve the dns successfully.

Also there has multiple troubleshooting step I search from here

[Troubleshotting: Cannot get a VPC-peered EFS accesspoint to mount](https://repost.aws/questions/QUvJFK8DpaQH631PQH8kfUGw/cannot-get-a-vpc-peered-efs-accesspoint-to-mount)

I hope it helps.